# conditional fill in values into specific row in a data table with R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table table as below: 
df

```
KEY    CAT      DATE   AMOUNT     VAR            VALUE
1      26    2015/10/1  1400 Event.Budget_Cat26   NA
1      26    2015/10/1  300  Event.Budget_Cat26   NA
1      26    2015/10/1  NA        NA              NA
1      22    2015/10/1  100  Event.Budget_Cat22   NA
1      22    2015/10/1  300  Event.Budget_Cat22   NA
1      22    2015/10/1  NA        NA              NA
2      21    2014/1/1   200  Event.Budget_Cat21   NA
2      21    2014/1/1   NA        NA              NA
```

This is just part of the large table. Basically, each row is unique by (KEY,CAT, DATE). I want to find a way to figure out the sum of amount based on the unique identify and put the final sum into VALUE column. 
Also, give a name to the VAR. The AMOUNT columns exist just for the VALUE columns and I will delete the whole columns in the end, so keep it as NA is okay.

The final result will be something like

```
KEY    CAT      DATE   AMOUNT     VAR                 VALUE
1      26    2015/10/1  1400 Event.Budget_Cat26        NA
1      26    2015/10/1  300  Event.Budget_Cat26        NA
1      26    2015/10/1  NA   Scalar.Budget_Cat26_Amt  1700
1      22    2015/10/1  100  Event.Budget_Cat22        NA
1      22    2015/10/1  300  Event.Budget_Cat22        NA
1      22    2015/10/1  NA   Scalar.Budget_Cat22_Amt   400
2      21    2014/1/1   200  Event.Budget_Cat21        NA
2      21    2014/1/1   NA   Scalar.Budget_Cat21_Amt   200
```

I have try the rbind and lapply, but the result is not what I want

```
df[, 4:6 := lapply(.SD, 
       function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), c("",paste("Scalar_Budget_Cat",CAT,"_Amt",sep =""),sum(x, na.rm=TRUE))), 
             KEY, .SDcols=4]
```

Could anyone help me to figure out a fast way to run through the whole data table, which contains 2,600,000 rows?  Thank you

Comment: Not sure if its fast but try `df[, VALUE:=sum(AMOUNT, na.rm = T),by=list(KEY, CAT, DATE)][is.na(VAR), VAR:=paste0("Scalar_Budget_Cat",CAT,"_Amt"),]`

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to create 'VALUE' with the `sum` of 'AMOUNT' after grouping by 'KEY', 'CAT', 'DATE' and later changing those values to `NA` based on whether it is not the last value for group.  Instead of doing that, we use `rep` to create `NA` and `sum` of 'AMOUNT' for the 'VALUE' column and modifying the 'VAR' column to have the last element for each group with `Scalar' substring

```
setDT(df1)[, c("VAR", "VALUE") := .(c(VAR[-.N], paste0("Scalar.", 
  sub("^[^.]+\\.", "", VAR[1]), "_Amt")), rep(c(NA, sum(AMOUNT, na.rm = TRUE)),
          c(.N-1, 1))), .(KEY, CAT, DATE)]
df1
#   KEY CAT      DATE AMOUNT                     VAR VALUE
#1:   1  26 2015/10/1   1400      Event.Budget_Cat26    NA
#2:   1  26 2015/10/1    300      Event.Budget_Cat26    NA
#3:   1  26 2015/10/1     NA Scalar.Budget_Cat26_Amt  1700
#4:   1  22 2015/10/1    100      Event.Budget_Cat22    NA
#5:   1  22 2015/10/1    300      Event.Budget_Cat22    NA
#6:   1  22 2015/10/1     NA Scalar.Budget_Cat22_Amt   400
#7:   2  21  2014/1/1    200      Event.Budget_Cat21    NA
#8:   2  21  2014/1/1     NA Scalar.Budget_Cat21_Amt   200
```

Comment: Hi akrun. Thank you so much. It does the job with a nice speed. The only drawback is the complexity. It takes me so time to understand the whole thing. I super appreciate your help!!

Comment: @VeraShao  Updated the post with some explanation

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on 2.6 million rows and it is really fast. We split the task in two operations. The first one is to group the rows by `KEY`, `CAT` and `DATE` and then sum over the `AMOUNT` column. After that we select the rows where `is.na(VAR) == T` and fill the `VAR` column with the corresponding string.

```
df[, VALUE:=sum(AMOUNT, na.rm = T),by=list(KEY, CAT, DATE)][is.na(VAR), VAR:=paste0("Scalar_Budget_Cat",CAT,"_Amt"),]
```

The difference to your desired output is, that there are no more `NA` values in `VALUE`. But that can be set back afterwards using `df[!is.na(AMOUNT), VALUE:=NA,]`

Comment: Hi Martin. Thank you! It is a such a easy way with fast speed. I did not even think about that I can use AMOUNT column in that way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

KEY <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
CAT <- c(26, 26, 26, 22, 22, 22, 21,21)
DATE <- c('2015/10/1', '2015/10/1', '2015/10/1', '2015/10/1', '2015/10/1', '2015/10/1', '2014/1/1', '2014/1/1')
AMOUNT <- c(1400, 300, NA, 100, 300, NA, 200, NA)
VAR <- c('Event.Budget_Cat26', 'Event.Budget_Cat26', NA, 'Event.Budget_Cat22', 'Event.Budget_Cat22', NA, 'Event.Budget_Cat21', NA)

df <- data_frame(KEY, CAT, DATE, AMOUNT, VAR, VALUE = NA)

summary_rows <- df %>%
  group_by(KEY, CAT, DATE) %>%
  summarise(VAR = paste0('Scalar.Budget_Cat', max(CAT), '_Amt'),
            VALUE = sum(AMOUNT, na.rm = T),
            AMOUNT = NA) %>%
  select(KEY, CAT, DATE, AMOUNT, VAR, VALUE) %>%
  arrange(KEY, -CAT, DATE)

df[is.na(AMOUNT),] <- summary_rows

df

##     KEY   CAT      DATE AMOUNT                     VAR VALUE
##   <dbl> <dbl>     <chr>  <dbl>                   <chr> <dbl>
## 1     1    26 2015/10/1   1400      Event.Budget_Cat26    NA
## 2     1    26 2015/10/1    300      Event.Budget_Cat26    NA
## 3     1    26 2015/10/1     NA Scalar.Budget_Cat26_Amt  1700
## 4     1    22 2015/10/1    100      Event.Budget_Cat22    NA
## 5     1    22 2015/10/1    300      Event.Budget_Cat22    NA
## 6     1    22 2015/10/1     NA Scalar.Budget_Cat22_Amt   400
## 7     2    21  2014/1/1    200      Event.Budget_Cat21    NA
## 8     2    21  2014/1/1     NA Scalar.Budget_Cat21_Amt   200
```